# Kendoui grid : Remember expanded detail grids on refresh

Tags: kendo-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remember expanded detail grids on refresh in Kendo-UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095392/remember-expanded-detail-grids-on-refresh-in-kendo-ui)

I have a scenario with grid within grid implemented using the detailInit method. Here when user makes edit, i  do some calculations that will change the data in the both parent and child. and then to refresh data, i will call the datasource.read to render data. this works and the data is displayed, however any detail grid which are expanded will be collapsed, is there any way i can prevent this from happening.

Comment: Funny, i asked a question 2012-04-22, get no reply, then this same thing is copied and asked on 2012-08-23 and my question gets closed as exact duplicate............ :-) Just a rant...