# Kendo ui grid expand detailini row after refreshing the grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I know this question has been posted a few times, and i´ve been reading about those solutions, but i need some help figuring out what am i missing.

What i want is the master grid to expand the last expanded row after a READ call, so i´ve read [this](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/persist-expanded-rows) and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25029806/retain-expanded-rows-after-databinding-kendo-ui-grid) but nothing seems to work, my code is this:

```
detailExpand: function (e) 
{
  var grid = $("#gridTimesheets").data("kendoGrid");
  expandedRowUid = e.masterRow.data('uid');
}
```

then on my master databound function i have this:

```
dataBound: function(e) 
{
  this.expandRow($('tr[data-uid=' + expandedRowUid + ']'));
}
```

the only thing that seems to expand the rows after the refresh is this:

```
this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row"));
```

but it expands all rows, i want only the last row before the READ method.

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that anytime data is rendered, all *uid*s are re-created. So you can't store an *old* uid, because it will be lost. I suggest you to store the row index:

```
detailInit: function(e) {
    $(e.detailCell).text("inner content");
    lastRowIndex = $(e.masterRow).index(".k-master-row");
}
```

Then find the row by index inside the `dataBound`:

```
dataBound: function() {
    var row = $(this.tbody).find("tr.k-master-row:eq(" + lastRowIndex + ")");
    this.expandRow(row);
}
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/erEtU)

Answer (score 0):

**Add javascript function to expand button on DataBound function**

```
 function dataBound() {
    this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row td a.k-i-expand").attr('onclick','SetWidthOnExpand()')
}

 function SetWidthOnExpand() {
   setTimeout(function () {
        $('.k-header').removeAttr('style');
        $('.k-selectable tbody tr td').removeAttr('style');
    },1000)
}
```